# Prometheus, blackbox exporter

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring

I'm using Prometheus and I need to monitor multiple ports, but I couldn't find information about that. Blackbox exporter docs aren't enough because that only pertains to monitoring one port.

I'm using Ubuntu Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on what you expect from the ports. If you just want to check if a port is open, you probably want to go with `tcp` prober. This one is configured in your `blackbox.yml` (like this):

```
modules:
[...]
  tcp_connect:
    prober: tcp
[...]
```

Now, you are able to make different checks using your `prometheus.yml`, like this:

```
scrape_configs:
[...]
  - job_name: 'my-tcp-probes'
    scrape_interval: 10s # whatever you want
    metrics_path: /probe # where your blackbox-exporter is running (see below)
    params:
      module: [tcp_connect] # most be equal to the one you configured in your blackbox.yml
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - host0:1234
          - host1:22
          [...]
          - hostN:3389
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: 127.0.0.1:9115 # host:port where blackbox exporter runs
```

Works fine for me. ;)